# Android animation - Transform button to progress loading

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

I'm developing an Android app which has a sign in page. When user click on login button, it will transform to the progress loading like the below

[Transform button to progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPGO7.gif)

I have no idea how to create this animation. Please give me an idea for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create two components with same position in layout: one VISIBLE, another INVISIBLE. Make ProgressBar have the same size as button by setting fixed width/height on both. Create two simultaneous animations: size change and cross-fade. Problem solved.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly, pls? the button scale down and translate to center. After that, it transform to progressbar

Comment: I don't think, that you will have to translate it, just center both components in parent layout. The "transform" can be simple size change, followed by cross-fade, or if you want to go nuts, — 1. Fade out button text (animate text color to transparent) 2. Set button background to AnimationDrawable (e.g. frame-by-frame shape change animation) 3. A bit of quick cross-fade. Keep animations quick, and user won't notice any of that.